# What kind of reasoner is produced by GenericRuleReasonerFactory?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, semantic-web, jena-rules

I have designed some rules and am wondering what the reasoner is is returned by the Jena's [GenericRuleReasonerFactory](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/GenericRuleReasonerFactory.html) (as shown in the following code)? Is it Racer, Pellet, or HermiT?

```
Reasoner reasoner = GenericRuleReasonerFactory.theInstance().create(configuration);
```

Comment: This is answered in the documentation, [Reasoners and rule engines: Jena inference support](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/).  As its name suggests, it uses the [generic rule reasoner](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#rules).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it answered plainly in the documentation (http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#rules), and such questions usually aren't needed on Stack Overflow (see the meta post, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208372/225437).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Jena's own rules engine.

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/index.html#rules